# ANDROID : ConstraintLayout : layout_constraintVertical_bias not working as expected

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

So I am trying to learn about the new `ConstraintLayout` stuff, as an iOS developer things seem ok.

This is my view [image]

What I am trying to do is to get the 4 squares to be slightly different sizes on the vertical axis (so pink 60%, blue below 40%, blue on the right 40%, black 60%)

Reading up on `layout_constraintVertical_bias`, this should do what I want however it seems to do nothing

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/left_guideline"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="58dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.16111112" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/right_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="306dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="434dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/yourStoryButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageButton
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/leftTopButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/leftBottomButton"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left_main_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/rightTopButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6"
        app:srcCompat="@color/colorAccent" />

    <ImageButton
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/rightTopButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rightBottomButton"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/leftTopButton"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_main_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4"
        app:srcCompat="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <ImageButton
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/leftBottomButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/leftTopButton"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left_main_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/rightBottomButton"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4"
        app:srcCompat="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rightBottomButton"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/leftBottomButton"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_main_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rightTopButton"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6"

        app:srcCompat="@android:color/background_dark" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/left_main_guideline"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.0"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/right_main_guideline"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1.0"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="360dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Am I incorrect that `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias` controls the growth percentage of that view (like weight did)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather than setting `layout_constraintVertical_bias` set this `layout_constraintVertical_weight`

Comment: That works perfectly (I was writing my own answer) do you know what layout_constraintVertical_bias actually does then

Comment: Bias are used for arranging the views if the parent has more space in that particular axis than the view's size. By default, they have 0.5 bias ,means they are centered. If you want to align them in any particular direction, use bias.  Have a better look here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html in bias section.

Answer (score 9):

To make it work you should also specify `chainStyle`

```
app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
```

Answer (score 3):

So, I am still baffled by what `layout_constraintVertical_bias` should do, however `app:layout_constraintVertical_weight` did what I expected `layout_constraintVertical_bias` to do

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/left_guideline"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="58dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.16111112" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/right_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="306dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="434dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/yourStoryButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageButton
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/leftTopButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/leftBottomButton"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left_main_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/rightTopButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0.6"
        app:srcCompat="@color/colorAccent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rightTopButton"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rightBottomButton"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/leftTopButton"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_main_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0.4"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />

    <ImageButton
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/leftBottomButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/leftTopButton"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left_main_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/rightBottomButton"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0.4"
        app:srcCompat="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rightBottomButton"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/leftBottomButton"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_main_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rightTopButton"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0.6"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/background_dark" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/left_main_guideline"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.0"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/right_main_guideline"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1.0"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="360dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Oh glad, you found it.